# Faraday::ConnectionFailed (Failed to open TCP connection to api.arknode.net:4001

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, faraday

I am using `ark-ruby` gem and that code

```
client = Ark::Client.new(
  :ip => 'api.arknode.net',
  :port => '4001',
  :nethash => '6e84d08bd299ed97c212c886c98a57e36545c8f5d645ca7eeae63a8bd62d8988',
  :version => '1.0.1'
)
```

But it gives an error on heroku that `Faraday::ConnectionFailed (Failed to open TCP connection to api.arknode.net:4001 (Connection refused - connect(2) for "api.arknode.net" port 4001)):`

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

api.arknode.net has been non-responsive for about a week. HTTPS should be used for that URL. You can try changing that to 5.39.9.240 port 4001 for now and just HTTP.

Note: The network is set up with a list of seed servers. You should use a seed server to get a list of peers in which to make API calls. https://ark.brianfaust.me/#/Peer/peers_getPeers.